# Why are $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] and $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] not set?

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, basic-authentication

Before I begin, I'd like to point out that I've browsed Stack Overflow and found other similar questions - [PHP_AUTH_USER not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663520/php-auth-user-not-set) and [HTTP Auth via PHP - PHP_AUTH_USER not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053306/http-auth-via-php-php-auth-user-not-set) - and these have pointed out that the authentication $_SERVER variables won't be set if ''Server API'' is set to ''CGI/FCGI'', but I checked my ''phpinfo()'' output and my ''Server API'' is set to ''Apache 2.0 Handler''.

Ok so I have a simple script as follows:

```
<?php
    echo "Username: " . $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] . ", Password: " . $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];
?>
```

... which I am calling remotely via the following:

```
wget -v --http-user=johnsmith --http-password=mypassword http://www.example.com/myscript.php
```

... but which only outputs:

```
Username: , Password:
```

I have also tried calling the script using PHP cURL and setting the authentication parameters appropriately as follows:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "johnsmith:mypassword");
```

... but I get the same output as above.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Perhaps there is something else I need to enable / configure?

Comment: Are you sending the correct response code?

Comment: Thanks Iganacio, could you please elaborate what you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally discovered the answer thanks to the of help of Naktibalda in ##php on irc.freenode.net

The following page summarises the issue: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

To quote the relevant bits:

> As of PHP 4.3.0, in order to prevent someone from writing a script which reveals the password for a page that was authenticated through a traditional external mechanism, the PHP_AUTH variables will not be set if external authentication is enabled for that particular page and safe mode is enabled. Regardless, REMOTE_USER can be used to identify the externally-authenticated user. So, you can use $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].
>
> ...
>
> PHP uses the presence of an AuthType directive to determine whether external authentication is in effect.

Answer (score 16):

For PHP-CGI:

in .htaccess add this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

and at the beginning of your script add this:

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

Comment: How would this work if the password contains a colon?

Answer (score 3):

Tried the previous suggestions, did not work, also discovered

```
CGIPassAuth On
```

is a more up to date version of the suggested htaccess addition, but that still did not work for me, instead I used

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

(must be in your root htaccess file) then in the php file

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

If anyone still has trouble I suggest they check the server vars, as the data may be in a different var, your looking for something that start with basic

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but in case someone stumbles accross this and can't get any of the solutions to work…

I had to pass the Header-Information to a redirected script. None of the above was working.

So I did the following:

in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^my_script/my_action$ /redirect_url/?auth=%{HTTP:Authorization} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

And then in the PHP-Script:

```
if (isset($_GET['auth']) && trim($_GET['auth']) != '') {
   list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_GET['auth'], 6)));
}
```

That way the base64 encoded basic authorization is added to the GET-Request-Vars and can be parsed in the receiving PHP-Script.

Not very elegant, probably a security risk, but it works in my scenario.

Comment: "*Probably* a security risk"? You're kidding?

Comment: Moreover, it just makes no sense. You just had to configure the server where redirect_url points to

Comment: I can't configure the server that way. It's an app that I can't change that accesses an URL on my server that doesn't exist anymore. So I had to use redirect. And - as I said, none of the suggestions above have been working. If you have a better solution, I'm all ears!

Answer (score -7):

this should be like this

```
echo "Username: " . $_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER] . ", Password: " . $_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_PW];
```

Comment: you are wrong. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php you have to use strings for an index so it have to be:  `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` etc.