# How to configure Apache to allow authentication in PHP

Tags: php, apache

My Log-In page isn't working like it does in localhost. I refactored the PHP page and relevant scripts but nothing worked until I stumbled on Apache-PHP-module configuration issue in my searches.

I've read and tried suggestions at:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php
- [Why are $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] and $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724127/why-are-serverphp-auth-user-and-serverphp-auth-pw-not-set)
- [PHP_AUTH_USER not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663520/php-auth-user-not-set)

... but none of them worked for me. Maybe, my problem's unique. Maybe not.

So far,
.htaccess has:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
     </IfModule>

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^genieverse.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my_site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

While log_in.php has:

```
 //Get custom error function script
require_once('Server_Includes/scripts/common_scripts/feature_error_message.php');

if(preg_match('/Basic\s+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'],      $matches))
{ list($the_name,  $the_password) = explode(':', base64_decode($matches[1]));
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = strip_tags($the_name);
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = strip_tags($the_password); }
//Filter incoming values
$username    =    (isset($_POST["username"])) ? trim($_POST["username"])    :     "Username";
$password = (isset($_POST["password"])) ? trim($_POST["password"])    :    "Password";
```

..... rest continues on to the log_in page form.

Everytime i enter Username and Password then click Submit, Log in page reloads requesting same. It's like they are never sent.

What do I need to do exactly?

PS:
Web server is shared hosting, Apache 2.2.31, PHP 5.4.45

Answer (score -2):

Never mind. I've solved it.:
I had a custom php.ini  file uploaded. It included:
    session.auto_start = On

But this didn't work. Neither did any form of htaccess hack work. So I created a phpinfo.php file with: