# page is available using any credentials on php authentication

Tags: php

popup dialog is there but entering any credentials - the page is available
what is the problem ?

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) || !$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'lorem' || !$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'ipsum'){
    header('http/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Wonder Penguin"');
    die("Access Denied !");
}
```

Comment: Checkout [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724127/why-are-serverphp-auth-user-and-serverphp-auth-pw-not-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724127/why-are-serverphp-auth-user-and-serverphp-auth-pw-not-set)

Comment: @HritikR - I have no problem with setting variables, but with their values. Otherwise the popup form would not be present

Comment: `!$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'lorem'` is wrong, you want `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != 'lorem'` there. (Or you would have to use an additional set of braces there, `!($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'lorem')`)

Comment: @CBroe - it works thanks a lot, you could write the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'lorem'` is wrong, you want
`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != 'lorem'` there.

Or you would have to use an additional set of braces there, `!($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'lorem')`

The reason is [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).