# Why are PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW actually set with external authentication?

Tags: php, authentication

I've found questions like this:

[Why are $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] and $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724127/why-are-serverphp-auth-user-and-serverphp-auth-pw-not-set)

Usually the question is why are PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW not set. And the explanation is usually:

> As of PHP 4.3.0, in order to prevent someone from writing a script which reveals the password for a page that was authenticated through a traditional external mechanism, the PHP_AUTH variables will not be set if external authentication is enabled for that particular page and safe mode is enabled. Regardless, REMOTE_USER can be used to identify the externally-authenticated user. So, you can use $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].
>
> ...
>
> PHP uses the presence of an AuthType directive to determine whether external authentication is in effect.
>
> Note, however, that the above does not prevent someone who controls a non-authenticated URL from stealing passwords from authenticated URLs on the same server.

The thing is that I have tried an example with external authentication, **and the PHP_AUTH variables are actually set**. I'm using PHP 7.4.3, so I suspect this explanation applies no more, because the first part has been removed from the current documentation. However you can still read the latter part:

> ```
> Note: Configuration Note
> PHP uses the presence of an AuthType directive to determine whether external authentication is in effect.
> ```
>
> Note, however, that the above does not prevent someone who controls a
> non-authenticated URL from stealing passwords from authenticated URLs
> on the same server.

So I'm confused. It seems these variables are set regardless of AuthType directives, but I really would like to confirm that point.

Thanks.

EDIT: (solution)

Thanks to the answer by @symcbean, I realized that in order to have the PHP_AUTH variables not set, safe mode had to be on. And after a bit of research, that safe mode option is removed from PHP. That's why this part was removed from the docs, and so here is the answer:

**PHP_AUTH variables will always be set, even in case of external authentication.**

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried an example with external authentication, and the PHP_AUTH variables are actually set

But you didn't show is the code. Did you read the source documentation you quoted here:

> will not be set if external authentication is enabled for that particular page ***and safe mode is enabled***

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot to make me realize (and sorry).

Comment: I've been researching that safe mode option, and it looks it's a deprecated thing. So at the end of the day, I assume that the right answer is: **yeah, currently those PHP_AUTH will always be set no matter what**.